# I am currently experimenting with simple addition by adding the values of three input elements

Tags: javascript

I am currently experimenting with simple addition by adding the values of three input elements.

I have three input elements and a button element with an `onclick` listener to invoke my function.  The function is to simply return the output of the sum of those values inputted by the user in an h2 element, and that is all.  Here are the HTML and JS:

```html
<div class="inputFields">
    <input class="lado" type="text" />
    <input class="lado" type="text" />
    <input class="lado" type="text" />
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="getArea()">click</button>
<h2 id="areaResult"></h2>
```

```js
var s1 = document.getElementsByClassName('lado')[0].value;
var s2 = document.getElementsByClassName('lado')[1].value;
var s3 = document.getElementsByClassName('lado')[2].value;

/*to my understanding, the .value property (like .innerHTML) renders a 
string value. Do please correct me if I'm wrong.*/

function getArea() {
    document.getElementById('areaResult').innerHTML =  
    Number(s1) + Number(s2) + Number(s3);  
    /*Utilized Number() method to convert the string values rendered by
    the .value properties to number values so as to perform addition 
    arithmetic operation rather than concatenation.*/ 
}
```

The output for some mysterious reason to me however is always `0` no matter what numbers I input or even if I input non-numerical characters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should move everything into `getArea`, so the values are taken from when you click the button, not from when javascript is being loaded.

Comment: Variable assignments do not extend into the future. The `var` on the left is set exactly *once*, when the line runs: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8d7ds6qL/

Comment: Ah hah.  I see.  I've done so and it works.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but to elaborate more on what you're saying; by making the variables local to `getArea()`, the variables are only assigned after function invocation?..opposed to if global, they're assigned as empty values?

Comment: @Chris, I see.  So although `a` is reassigned to `7`, `b` remains assigned to `5`.

Comment: @ScottMiller Btw: to always get the current value, you can use a function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8d7ds6qL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare all the variables inside the function.

You do not need to write `document.getElementsByClassName` every time. Simply use a variable to store all the class element then use index to get the value from that variable like the following:

```js
function getArea() {
    var lado = document.getElementsByClassName('lado');
    var s1 = lado[0].value;
    var s2 = lado[1].value;
    var s3 = lado[2].value;

    document.getElementById('areaResult').innerHTML =  
    Number(s1) + Number(s2) + Number(s3);
}
```

```html
<div class="inputFields">
    <input class="lado" type="text" />
    <input class="lado" type="text" />
    <input class="lado" type="text" />
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="getArea()">click</button>
<h2 id="areaResult"></h2>
```